# Why don't all System.Web.UI.WebControl classes with Text properties implement ITextControl?

Tags: asp.net, web-controls

I'm curious why only some `System.Web.UI.WebControl` controls implement certain interfaces when they have the same properties of an interface.

For instance, there are plenty of controls that have a Text property but only the following  implement `ITextControl`:

- Label
- Literal
- DataBoundLiteral
- TextBox
- ListControl

(TextBox and ListControl actually implement IEditableTextControl which implements ITextControl)

TableCell, Button, HyperLink and others don't so I have to write code like this

```
ITextControl textControl = control as ITextControl;
TableCell tableCell = control as TableCell;

if (textControl != null)
{
    textControl.Text = value;
}
else if (tableCell != null)
{
    tableCell.Text = value;
}
```

instead of this

```
control.Text = value;
```

Was this a design decision or an oversight?

Comment: Good question. I think the difference is between HtmlControl & a WebControl. But would love to hear more background on this one...

Comment: @Sunny I can understand if one is HtmlControl and the other is WebControl, but there are differences between various WebControls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it was designed ok, I don't think it was an oversight; those are the controls where text is the primary focus of the purpose of the control.  I do see your point because that would be very convenient to have controls utilize more of these types of interfaces.